# Run Apache TomEE 7.0.4 with JDK 9 and JDK 10

Tags: java, java-9, apache-tomee, tomee-7, java-10

I can not get TomEE 7.0.4 to work with java 9 and 10.
TomEE 7.0.4 does not work with java 9 and 10.
I think I understand that it is necessary to configure catalina.bat (I use windows).

If I understood correctly, it all depends on the modules of jdk 9.

I'm going crazy in finding a solution.

To please help me to understand how to configure TomEE (catalina.bat or other)?

Comment: "_can not get TomEE 7.0.4 to work with Java 9_" - You need to provide more details on what's the failure or the like!

Comment: @javista Please find my updated answer below.

Answer (score 3):

TomEE up to version 7.0.4 won't work with Java 9/10. This is due to the use of `org.apache.xbean.asm5` classes in the bundled OWB jars. The TomEE team is working hard to resolve these issues, has integrated ASM 6.1 already and the upcoming release of TomEE 7.0.5 will thus be compatible with Java 9/10.

So, you have to stick with Java 8 for a while until TomEE 7.0.5 has been released and is [available for download](https://tomee.apache.org/download-ng.html). Check this link in the next weeks for updates.

Hope it helps.

### UPDATE:

On July 23rd, TomEE 7.0.5 was released. It runs fine with Java 9 and 10. I tested it on all three major OS platforms. Check the download link above for the release artifacts.

Comment: Has been an issue logged on any TomEE forums that confirms this @MWiesner? Just curious!

Comment: From the mailing list, e.g.: 
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomee-dev/201805.mbox/<CA0BC05B-14BC-4BD3-869E-6B771CF92988@yahoo.de>

Comment: Or here: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-7-0-5-work-td4683763.html